# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement when executing test through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, classcastexception

I'm trying make an automation test in Selenium WebDriver, but Eclipse is showing me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

Here is my code:

```
public void SeachApp()
{
    Object elem = driver.getPageSource().contains("Staffing");

    if (elem != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Encontrado");
        int width = ((WebElement) elem).getSize().getWidth();

        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement((WebElement) elem)
            .moveByOffset((width / 2) - 15, 0)
            .click()
            .perform();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Não Encontrado");
        }
    }
```

What's going on, and how can I fix this?

Comment: `driver.getPageSource()` return you String and `driver.getPageSource().contains("Staffing")` return you boolean not WebElement, you cannot cast it to WebElement. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need to click on a WebElement that has the ID dynamic, so I will search by text Object elem = driver.getPageSource().contains("Staffing") and after I'll try to get it position on Web page so click.

Comment: @DebanjanB explained good, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### getPageSource()

As per the documentation [**`getPageSource()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) returns the *source of the current page* and is defined as:

> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that the returned text is that of the modified page. You need to follow the documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text last sent by the web server. The page source returned is a representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be formatted or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server.

---

### contains()

The [**`contains()`**](https://www.guru99.com/string-contains-method-java.html) method is a *Java* method to check if the *String* contains another *substring* or not. It returns *boolean value* so it can use directly inside if statements.

---

### Analysis

The expression which you have used:

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("Staffing");
```

will return a *Boolean Value* but gets casted into an `Object` type of object. Further, as you are trying to cast an `Object` type of object to `WebElement` type you see the error as:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

---

### Solution

If you desire to locate a *WebElement* you have to use either of the following methods:

- [**`findElement()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [**`findElements`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

Now, if you desire to get hold of the *WebElement* with text as **Staffing** (without any reference to the relevant *HTML*) you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Staffing')]"));
```

Now, once you located the *WebElement*, you can easily perform the remaining of your tasks with the *WebElement*.